# Embedding data into HTML page from shell_exec

Tags: php, html, linux, embed

I am fairly new to web development, and am having a small issue.
I am creating an html website on a cluster that I administrate. I would like to have the server uptime displayed on the main page (index.html).

I have created a php script (called test.php) with the following code:

```
<?php
$uptime = shell_exec("cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime");
$days = floor($uptime/60/60/24);
$hours = $uptime/60/60%24;
$mins = $uptime/60%60;
$secs = $uptime%60;
echo "up $days days $hours hours $mins minutes and $secs seconds";
?>
```

The code works fine on its own when just viewing the test.php file, but I would like to have it so that I can have the same info on the index.html page.

I cannot figure out how to embed the php file into the html file.

Comment: Why not use `index.php` instead of `html` ?

Comment: **[`include`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe>` tags are considered **bad** practises, and you should not be adding a `<meta>` tag in the `<body>` either. Unless you have valid reasons, you should avoid them.

The simplest solution would be to use PHP instead of HTML for the index page.

However, if you *do* need to use HTML, you could fetch the uptime from your PHP file via Ajax and inject it into your HTML file. Here's an example, using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
        $(".uptime").html(data);
    }
});
```

Again, this is not the ideal solution, and you should really consider using PHP for your whole website instead.

Comment: I agree with you, in the many months since I posted this question, I have learned a lot more about web development. The reason I couldn't change it to .php was because a bunch of other websites link to the .html page (a redirect would have been another solution?). But now knowing how to do stuff, I would recommend this to anyone having this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Make the site .php instead of .html, it won't make a big difference. You can also use

```
<?php system("uptime"); ?>
```

As a variation.

Comment: `uptime` is different than `/proc/uptime`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, files is processed by web server.

**On Apache web server with PHP module** you can try write to the `.htaccess`(file can be at site directory):

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

OR

> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

---

**For Nginx with phpfpm** you should do two steps:

1. Firstly set `security.limit_extensions = .php .html` to **`php-fpm.conf`**
2. Secondly you should add to config of Nginx:

> ```
> location ~* \.(php|htm|html)$ {
>     fastcgi_pass ...
>     fastcgi_param ...
>     include fastcgi_params;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was just using an html iframe. So in my index.html in included the line

```
<iframe src="test.php"></iframe>
```

That got the job done for me
I added a refresh feature also by adding this line to the test.php file

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```